# How to negate bool value inside blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-blazor

I'm trying to do this

```
<MatCheckbox @bind-Value="@(!Checked)" Label="Checkbox"></MatCheckbox>
```

But it gives me the error

> CS0131    The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer

How can I pass a negated boolean value without creating another property?

I want to bind the value so it's `!Checked`

Comment: Create a property called "Unchecked" that negates Checked and bind to that instead.

Comment: `How can I pass a negated boolean value without creating another property?`

Comment: Yes, but a bind expression is a property, I don't think you can.

Comment: @DavidG now it's better explained, thanks

Comment: @DavidG could you write that as an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @DavidG said in the comments, you cannot bind a value, you need to bind a property, and `!Checked` returns a value, not a property.

So the only way to do this is by creating a negated property.

Comment: Ideally you should have offered me to write up the answer rather than post yourself. Something to consider for next time.

Comment: @DavidG please write it, and I erase my answer.

Comment: It doesn't matter now, I'm just saying for future posts.